# ng-click breaks the App if triggered by clikcing element from Shadow Dom

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, svg, shadow-dom

The idea is to keep SVGs in shadow DOM and insert them with 'use' tag.
The issue is in IE11 when adding ng-click to elements encapsulating SVGs.

```html
<a ng-href="#/settings/profile">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon--medium" name="cog">
        <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#cog"></use>
    </svg>
</a>
```

Same happens on clicking A tag or any element with attached ng-click.
After problem occurs, the UI stops responding. Only hard page reload fixes the issue.

Observed in IE only. Chrome works fine.

Any idea what can it be?

Answer (score 0):

Try add `pointer-events: none;` to the svg elements